# How to create a rest method in java that takes list of string as input

Tags: java, rest

I want create a rest method(http put) that takes a list of string as input in java. And want some sample code to invoke the same. Since I need to implement this in apex java sample will do well.

I will be more than happy if someone can provide samples for writing the apex method but for now java rest method will be ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you're using HTTP PUT anyway, why don't you use an aray of Strings written according to JSON notation? It's anyway what you'd expect, and it lets you extend in the future.

- Check the JSON syntax [here](http://json.org/)
- Consider using gson as a library to process it all, [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

Comment: am very new to this!
what is the best way of sending the Json in the requestbody or in the request params?
I have another doubt.. Json is some kinda key value pair i guess!

Comment: You typically use parameters on GET requests, and a body in POST and PUT. JavaScript is a classic way of encapsulating data because Javascript can evaluate that directly to an object. It's less formal than XML, and would probably do the work nicely. Json objects are key-value pairs, but values can be other objects, arrays, etc... Finally, in JSON, an array of strings would look like "[string1,string2,string3], which is anyway the most intuitive way of doing it. Maybe you don't want to use gson for something that simple yet. Anyways, we're probably over complicating this ;)